# xslt:key match with contains(text(),

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0, xslkey

I have to use xslt 1.0 and I have following xml:

```
<Root>
 <Alarm>
   <Name>short</Name>
    <FlagValues>Client, RunTime, Language</FlagValues>
 </Alarm>
 <Alarm>
   <Name>long</Name>
   <FlagValues>Client, Formatted, RunTime, Language</FlagValues>
 </Alarm>
</Root>
```

At the beginning of my xslt transformation I want to create a mapping with xsl:key.....
I need all "Alarm"-nodes where the string "Formatted" is in the "FlagValues"-node. The Key should be the "Name".

So here is my try:

`<xsl:key name="alarmNodes" match="Root/Alarm/FlagValues[contains(text(), 'Formatted')]" use="Name" />`

But when I try to access it, it is empty:

`<xsl:when test="key('alarmNodes', "'long'")">`

My expected result is a node-Object containing this:

```
 <Alarm>
   <Name>long</Name>
   <FlagValues>Client, Formatted, RunTime, Language</FlagValues>
 </Alarm>
```

Any ideas whats going wrong?

Thanks
Marcus

Comment: Did my answer help or are you still having trouble?

Answer (score 0):

You're selecting `FlagValues` in your match (and `FlagValues` doesn't have a child `Name`).

Try selecting `Alarm` instead...

```xml
<xsl:key name="alarmNodes" match="Root/Alarm[contains(FlagValues, 'Formatted')]" use="Name" />
```

You also have quoting issues in the `test` of your `xsl:when`, but you'd be getting an exception so that's probably just a typo.